# String.Format. Вывести только первый символ строки с большой буквы

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток. Формирую привязку строк в wpf к TextBlock. В Binding есть свойство StringFormat. Вопрос в следующем. Как при привязке, через StringFormat, отобразить только первый символ строки с большой буквы.

Comment: Думаю, невозможно, используйте конвертер.

Comment: @Vlad, Спасибо.

Comment: Думаю лучше свойство создать которое будет возвращать первый символ с учетом регистра

Comment: Ну или так, да.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю лучше свойство создать которое будет возвращать первый символ с учетом регистра